# How to rotate psp objects by anchoring the middle point in spatstat?

Tags: r, spatstat

I have a line segment pattern, which is in 90 degrees angle to another line:

```
require(spatstat)    
range <- c(0,10)

owin <- owin(xrange = range, yrange = range)

l1 <- psp(x0 = 8, x1 = 8, y0 = 2, y1 = 8, window = owin, marks = "l1")
l2 <- psp(x0 = 6, x1 = 6, y0 = 2, y1 = 8, window = owin, marks = "l2")
l3 <- psp(x0 = 4, x1 = 4, y0 = 2, y1 = 8, window = owin, marks = "l3")
l4 <- psp(x0 = 2, x1 = 2, y0 = 2, y1 = 8, window = owin, marks = "l4")

lines <- superimpose(l1, l2, l3, l4)

main <- psp(x0 = 8, x1 = 0, y0 = 5, y1 = 5, window = owin, marks = "main")

angles.psp(lines)*(180/pi)
[1] 90 90 90 90
```

Here is a visual representation:

```
plot(x = range, y = range, type = "n", main = "", asp = 1, axes = F, xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
plot(lines, col = "darkgrey", add = T)
plot(main, col = "black", add = T)
axis(1)
axis(2, las = 2)
```

[image]

Now I want to rotate `lines` so that they cross `main` at the same point but in 45 degrees angle.

```
lines.rotated <- rotate(lines, -0.7853982)
angles.psp(lines.rotated)*(180/pi)
[1] 45 45 45 45
```

This works, but `angles.psp` function seems to rotate the window (`owin`) instead of the lines separately as I want.

```
plot(x = range, y = range, type = "n", main = "", asp = 1, axes = F, xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
plot(lines, col = "darkgrey", add = T)
plot(lines.rotated, col = "blue", add = T)
plot(main, col = "black", add = T)
axis(1)
axis(2, las = 2)
```

[image]

**Is there a way to rotate all `lines` relative to `main` line such that the angle is 45 degrees, but the crossing point remains the same?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make the answer self contained. The following code should produce what you are looking for (if this is a useful function we could ask Adrian (maintainer of spatstat) to include an improved version of it in spatstat).
First the prerequisites:

```
require(spatstat)

linerotate.psp <- function(X, L, angle){
    ## Window:
    W <- as.owin(X)
    ## Empty psp object:
    Y <- psp(numeric(0),numeric(0),numeric(0),numeric(0),W)
    for(i in 1:X$n){
        ## Line i:
        Xi <- X[i]
        ## Crossing of line i and test line L in the window:
        cross <- crossing.psp(L, Xi)
        ## Rotate line if the crossing is non-empty:
        if(npoints(cross)>0){
            m <- as.numeric(coords(cross))
            ## Move to crossing:
            Xi <- affine(Xi, vec = -m)
            ## Rotate:
            Xi <- rotate(Xi, angle = angle)
            ## Move back:
            Xi <- affine(Xi, vec = m)
            ## Restrict to non-rotated window:
            Xi <- Xi[W]
        }
        ## Collect results:
        Y <- superimpose(Y, Xi)
    }
    return(Y)
}
```

The data:

```
W <- square(10)

x0 <- c(8,6,4,2)
x1 <- x0
y0 <- rep(2,4)
y1 <- rep(8,4)

lines <- psp(x0, y0, x1, y1, window = W)

main <- psp(x0 = 8, x1 = 0, y0 = 5, y1 = 5, window = W)
```

The rotated data and angle comparison:

```
rotlines <- linerotate.psp(lines, main, angle = -pi/4)
angles.psp(lines)*(180/pi)
[1] 90 90 90 90
angles.psp(rotlines)*(180/pi)
[1] 45 45 45 45
```

Graphically:

```
plot(lines, col = "darkgrey")
plot(main, col = "black", add = T)
plot(rotlines, col = "blue", add = T)
```

[image: Rotated lines]

Graphically with non-horizontal test line:

```
main <- psp(x0 = 0, x1 = 10, y0 = 3, y1 = 7, window = W)
rotlines <- linerotate.psp(lines, main, angle = -pi/4)

plot(lines, col = "darkgrey")
plot(main, col = "black", add = T)
plot(rotlines, col = "blue", add = T)
```

[image: rotated lines 2]

Comment: @EgeRubak Thank you. I think this is a better solution for the problem in the question than using an external package.  @PauloCardoso has a good point. Implementing that should not require very large changes to the code as one could relate `W` to `main`/additional optional line instead of `X`.

Comment: I had missed this point completely. Sorry about that. I will edit my answer with the modified code to find all intersections with a test line L and rotate each line a specified angle around this intersection.

Comment: I'm quite new to stackoverflow, so I'm not sure whether the best strategy is to edit your own answer or provide a new. Now that I look at my edited code the comment of @PauloCardoso no longer makes sense. Is it considered bad style to make such changes that an original comment no longer is relevant? On another note maybe the original poster should edit the title of the question since we no longer anchor the middle point, but an intersection point with another line.

Comment: @EgeRubak I don't think it is possible to answer twice to one question. Normally people leave the old answer and add edits below or above it. Yes, I am bad it finding fitting titles for my questions. Your answer is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: A note for someone who might wonder, why @EgeRubak's code does not work for the original example: `superimpose` function wants `marks` in the same format for all objects. I have previously solved this by running the function twice. First for `i=1` and then for loop `i in 2:n`, where I `superimpose` to `i=1` component. There got to be a more elegant way of doing this, though.

Comment: @EgeRubak You should keep the 1st version of your code and add a 2nd function with the rotation on intersection points. That would be a plus.

Comment: In this case it would be possible to solve the `marks` issue by adding this: `M <- marks(X); X <- unmark(X)` after creating `Y` and then this: `marks(Y) <- M` before `return(Y)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got your idea.

For a simplistic approach, could `elide` from maptools be an option?

something like this:

```
library(maptools)
# convert lines to SpatialLines
slines <- as(lines, 'SpatialLines')

plot(x = range, y = range, type = "n", main = "", asp = 1, axes = F,
     xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
plot(lines, col = "darkgrey", add = T)
plot(main, col = "black", add = T)
axis(1)
axis(2, las = 2)
# Plot slines object on top of your data
plot(elide(slines, rotate = 45, center = c(5, 5)), add = T)

# plot it
```

[image: rotated slines]

But you may want each line from rotated line crossing the intersection between line and main. Is that true?

If so, loop on each psp line. For psp l4:

```
plot(elide(slines[4], rotate = 45, center = c(2, 5)), add = T)
```

[image: plot on intersections]

You could coerce it back to psp with

```
as.psp.Lines(from, ..., window=NULL, marks=NULL, fatal)
```

Comment: The rotated lines are still not crossing `main` at same points than the original lines. I suppose it could work, if you used `elide` for each line separately. My application leans heavily to `spatstat` so I would like to find a way to do it with that package. Maybe writing the rotated lines as `psp` objects could work.